# Parsing a Boolean expression into a one memory machine using lex and yacc

Tags: c, abstract-syntax-tree, yacc, lex, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to write a small app that in a way simplifies a Boolean expression, the app will be using only one memory slot.
If needed more then one memory slot I wish to return a message stating that the app can't perform an evaluation of the expression.
I'm Using an AST I've built from lex and yacc.

The main Idea is to take a Boolean expression and convert it to something like this:

```
X==3 || y==3 && z==5 || x!=4
```

so the calculation will be linear from left to right
If given an expression like

```
x==3 || (y==3 && z==5)
```

Then I want it to be parsed into

```
y==3 && z==5 || x==3
```

This has an equivalent match and doesn't need to 'store' the result of x==3 into a register first. Therefor it use's only one memory slot and still return's the right result.
expressions such as:

```
(x==3 || y==4) && (t==3 || t>4)
```

are too complex
so is

```
x==3 || x==4 || (x==5 && x==6)
```

Since u can't parse it into one memory slot from an AST.
However bare in mind that The expression

```
x==4 && (x==3 && y==5) && p==5
```

is still viable and can be parsed into

```
x==3 && y==5 && x==4 && p==5
```

The ast that I have built using yacc has the following rules:

```
E -> E | E '||' T
T -> T | T '&&' F
F -> exp | '(' E ')'
```

exp -> create's the expressions like x==3, there's no recursive concepts here, this lead's to the end of the rules.

I'm not sure if the tree should be built dif but the problem I'm having is that the 2 Boolean expressions:

```
1. x==4 && (x==3 && y==5) && p==5
2. x==3 || x==4 && (x==5 && x==6)
```

generate the same AST, well almost the same, the diff between the 2 are very minor and they mirror one another.
I can't seem to find a rule of thumb to tell me which is 'too complicated' and which is not.
Of course those 2 expressions can generate much more complex ones, but they need to follow the same rules.

You can assume that the app itself obviously has memory and only parsing the expression and has access to the full power of c.

Thank's a lot in advance

Comment: Can you explain your "one memory machine"? I don't see why any of the expressions you've shown would require more than one register/memory slot using any machine model that I can imagine (except those where any comparison requires two registers of course). I also don't see why your transformations would reduce the number of required registers.

Comment: The machine is an old one that simply work's that way. When you calculate in the linear form I showed above, u only 'store' the result of the last exp. But when u calculate exp like x==3 && (), the machine technically need's to save the result of x==3 and then start calculate the parenthesis (which will require an additional memory). BUT if u convert it into a linear form back again then problem solved. The thing is, not every expression can be transformed so it will give the same result - ty in advance

Comment: "the machine" or "the code"???

Comment: mmm the code is designed to work on an old machine, that can only compute stuff in a linear form, I am not the original design of this. Basically I'm trying to create a sort of parser to expend the possibilities for future use

Comment: "The machine is an old one that simply work's that way." That simply works *what* way? You need to explain how your machine works and under which circumstances it requires additional memory. Equivalently you could explain into which exact form you need to transform your expression. "exp like x==3 && ()" So does that mean you need extra memory only for expressions with parentheses? I find it hard to imagine a machine where `x==3 || y==3 && z==5 || x!=4` would require no extra memory, but `(x==3 || y==4) && (t==3 || t>4)` would. Note that all your expressions can be rewritten without parentheses